# Migration of PMD configuration from 5.1 to 5.4

Tags: java, eclipse, pmd

I used [eclipse-pmd](https://acanda.github.io/eclipse-pmd/index.html) version 0.9 with Eclipse Kepler. Now I use eclipse-pmd version 1.7 with Eclipse Mars.

I tried to use the same PMD configuration (reduced to one rule):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset>
    <rule ref="rulesets/java/basic.xml/EmptyCatchBlock">
        <priority>1</priority>
    </rule>
</ruleset>
```

but I get always the message:

> pmd.xml is not a valid PMD rule set configuration

What is wrong with that rule set?

[Changelog](https://acanda.github.io/eclipse-pmd/changelog.html) of eclipse-pmd says that PMD changed from 5.1 to 5.4.

I found a [Migration guide](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.1.1/rules/java/migrating.html) for PMD 5.1.1, but not for PMD 5.4. Is there any migration guide for PMD 5.4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, see [changelog](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pmd/files/pmd/5.4.0/):

> **Removed Rules:**
>
> - Basic: The following rules of ruleset "Basic" were marked as deprecated and are removed with this release now:
>     EmptyCatchBlock, EmptyIfStatement, EmptyWhileStmt, EmptyTryBlock, EmptyFinallyBlock, EmptySwitchStatements, EmptySynchronizedBlock, EmptyStatementNotInLoop, EmptyInitializer, EmptyStatementBlock, EmptyStaticInitializer UnnecessaryConversionTemporary, UnnecessaryReturn, UnnecessaryFinalModifier, UselessOverridingMethod, UselessOperationOnImmutable, UnusedNullCheckInEquals, UselessParentheses These rules are still available in the rulesets "Empty" (rulesets/java/empty.xml) and "Unnecessary" (rulesets/java/unnecessary.xml) respectively.

After removing all rules starting with "Empty" fom PMD configuration, I could import it.